# How to ignore error result in Kafka Connect Elasticsearch

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to run kafka connect for elastic search .
But because of some mistake i entered wrong record in kafka topic .

Now i fixed that issue and inserting correct value but elastic search is still throwing error on previous record in the topic

Here is the error

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'lambdaDemo0': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"lambdaDemo0-9749-0e710000fd04"; line: 1, column: 13]
```

Is there any way i can ignore the older record in the topic and tell kafka connect to pick latest record  ?
I am trying to delete the topic i get topic marked for deletion but still records are present in the topic .

I tried below two properties but does seems to be working

```
drop.invalid.message=true
behavior.on.malformed.documents=ignore
```

Please suggest how i can clean up the wrong record in the topic

Comment: How about purging your Kafka topic and re-insert the correct records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Kafka Connect to just skip bad records

```
errors.tolerance = all
```

Optionally, you can route these messages to another topic (known as a dead letter queue) for inspection by adding

```
errors.tolerance = all
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name = my-dlq-topic
```

These settings are valid for Kafka Connect with any connector that is failing in the serialisation/deserialisation stage of processing. For more information see [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/).